# How to iterate in python with two lists of different lengths

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate with two lists and I want the for statement to be exhaustive with both lists.

Example

```
Month = [1,2,3]
Year = [2018,2019]
```

So in my for statement I have

```
for i,j in zip(Month, Year):
print i,j
```

So that I get

```
1,2018
2,2018
3,3018
1,2019
2,2019
3,2019
```

Comment: That is not a zip. That is a cartesian product.

Comment: The opposite problem is far more common: people accidentally write the correct code for what you want to do, when they want `zip`, because they don't know about `zip`.